# Is it possible to use a depth renderbuffer with cubemap color attachment?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, framebuffer

I am trying to create a Framebuffer, with a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP as the Color Attachment, and GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 as the Depth Attachment for the Framebuffer's Renderbuffer.

I was confident that this would work, as it did for a Framebuffer with a GL_TEXTURE_2D Color Attachment and a Renderbuffer with GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8 as the Depth Component. However, it does not seem to work for a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP color attachment, because I get a  Framebuffer Incomplete error. Also, note that I am trying to create multiple Framebuffers all at once.

```
glGenFramebuffers(5, &FBO[0]);
glGenTextures(5, &FBO_texture[0]);
glGenRenderbuffers(5, &FBO_Renderbuffer[0]);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, FBO_texture[i]);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + j, 0, GL_R16F, shadow_map_width, shadow_map_height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO[i]);

    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, FBO_texture[i], 0);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, FBO_Renderbuffer[i]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, shadow_map_width, shadow_map_height);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, FBO_Renderbuffer[i]);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        LOGGER->log(ERROR, "Renderer :  createFrameBuffers ", "Framebuffer is incomplete!");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
}
```

I can't understand why I get a Framebuffer incomplete error. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You have to create a `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`texture with the format `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` for the depth buffer attachment. For instance:

```cpp
glGenFramebuffers(5, &FBO[0]);
glGenTextures(5, &FBO_texture[0]);
glGenTextures(5, &FBO_depth_texture[0]);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, FBO_texture[i]);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + j, 0, GL_R16F, shadow_map_width, shadow_map_height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, FBO_depth_texture[i]);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + j, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, shadow_map_width, shadow_map_height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO[i]);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, FBO_texture[i], 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, FBO_depth_texture[i], 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        LOGGER->log(ERROR, "Renderer :  createFrameBuffers ", "Framebuffer is incomplete!");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works!  This doesn't give any completeness errors.